# Highcharts scatter chart Tooltip gets closed when i hover on tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a scatter chart which is made using Highcharts and when I hover on each data points I am showing another chart inside the tooltip. when I hover on the tooltip about halfway from middle to top the tooltip is getting closed. also when I hover on the chart inside the tool tip the chart keeps re rendering. Please fnd attached code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scatter_container" style="height: 90vh;"></div>

    <script>
        function renderChart(point) {
            (async () => {

                const data = await fetch(
                    'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json'
                ).then(response => response.json());

                // Create the chart
                Highcharts.stockChart('hc-tooltip', {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'AAPL',
                        data: data,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 2
                        }
                    }]
                });
                })();
        }

        Highcharts.addEvent(
            Highcharts.Tooltip,
            'refresh',
            function () {
                renderChart(this.chart.hoverPoint);
            }
        );

        const series = [{
            name: 'Basketball',
            id: 'basketball',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                width: 32,
                height: 32
            }
        }];

        async function getData() {
            // const response = await fetch(
            //     'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/olympic2012.json'
            // );
            const response = await fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/qs/65b8d298dc746540189dacb7');
            return response.json();
        }


        getData().then(data => {
            const getData = sportName => {
                const temp = [];
                data.record.forEach(elm => {
                    // if (elm.sport === sportName && elm.weight > 0 && elm.height > 0) {
                        temp.push([elm.height, elm.weight]);
                    // }
                });
                return temp;
            };
            series.forEach(s => {
                s.data = getData(s.id);
            });

            Highcharts.chart('scatter_container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'scatter',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Olympics athletes by height and weight',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text:'',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Height'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value} m'
                    },
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    showLastLabel: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Weight'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value} kg'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stickyTracking: false
                    },
                    scatter: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2.5,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        jitter: {
                            x: 0.005
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits:{
                enabled:false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    split: true,
                    stickOnContact: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    headerFormat: '',
                    pointFormat: '<div id="hc-tooltip" style="width:320px;height:45vh;"></div>'
                },
                series
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tooltip automatically hides after leaving the plot area after `500` milliseconds. You can change this using the `tooltip.hideDelay` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.hideDelay